# Apex - retrieve account histories from Contact

Tags: apex, soql, history-tracking

I have a requirement, where I need to retrieve Account history while querying Contact object.

Is it possible something like below?

SELECT ID, Account.id, (SELECT field, currentvalue, previousvalue FROM AccountHistory) FROM CONTACT.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly query `AccountHistory` from a `Contact` as a parent-child subquery can only be 1 level deep, and there must be a direct relationship from the parent object to the child object.

Instead, to accomplish this, you'll need to gather a collection of `Account` Ids referenced by the collection of `Contacts` that you're working with, and either query `AccountHistory` directly, or query for `Accounts` and include the parent-child subquery.

An example:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact cont :contacts){
    accountIds.add(cont.AccountId);
}

List<Account> accountsWithHistories = [SELECT Id, (SELECT oldValue, newValue, field FROM AccountHistories) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds];
```

Comment: I was using List<Id> whenever I had to use collection inside SOQL with IN. Nice use of Set<Id>.

Comment: Yeah, I like having the assurance that there won't be any duplicate Ids (which has caused some dml errors for me in the past) in the collection. It also simplifies checking for and removing/not adding null Ids with `someIdSet.remove(null);`

Comment: It makes perfect sense here. In case if we have knowledge that Id's were unique in different scenario (say SOQL is [Select Id from Account]), would you recommend List<Id>  ? coz I assume Set comes with a extra cost of validating and removing dups on every set.add(entry).

Comment: @karthikselvakumar This is starting to get off-topic, and might be a decent question (if it hasn't already been asked). The underlying implementation of `Sets` are a Java `HashMap`, which generally has an insertion complexity of O(1). Basically, it's fast, don't worry about any additional overhead, it's practically non-existent.

Comment: I found this question in recent list and thought it would be helpful http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110320/when-to-use-set-vs-list-in-soql